# Method search on google sheet data from one column using google script?

Tags: javascript, search

I had tried to search data like below flow picture and script to search data from google sheet using google app script but the script using is not working properly but can someone tell me how to setup search function to find data like flow on image? thanx

[Flow searching data][1]

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Search", functionName: "searchRecord"} ];
  ss.addMenu("Commands", menuEntries);    
}

function searchRecord()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var wsSearchingData = ss.getSheetByName("Searching Data")
  var wsDatabase = ss.getSheetByName("Database")
  var searchString = wsSearchingData.getRange("E4").getValue();

  var column =1; //column Index   
  var columnValues = wsDatabase.getRange(2, column, wsDatabase.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
  var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2

  var searchValue = wsDatabase.getRange("B2:B2041").getValues()
    
  var matchingDatabase = searchValue.map(searchColumn => {
    var matchColumn = columnValues.find(r => r[0] == searchColumn[0])

  return matchColumn = matchColumn ? [matchColumn[2]] : null
  })
  console.log(matchingDatabase)

  if(searchResult != -1)
  {
    //searchResult + 2 is row index.
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(searchResult + 1, 1))
  }
  
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == search) return i;
    wsSearchingData.getRange("B11").setValue(search[0]);
    wsSearchingData.getRange("C11").setValue(search[1]);
    wsSearchingData.getRange("D11").setValue(search[2]);
    wsSearchingData.getRange("E11").setValue(search[3]);
    wsSearchingData.getRange("F11").setValue(search[4]);
  return;
  } 
}
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF9K8.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2
```

replace the above code with:

```
var searchResult = columnValues.filter(r=>r[1]==searchString)
```

You can then put searchResult directly as output in the sheet. Make sure that [1] in the above contains the column index of Name in the columnValues Array.